# java using multiple classes and compiling

Tags: java, compilation

I'm just new to java .I made two java files. One is Main.java which contains the main method and the other one is Second.java which contains some fields and methods. After that I created the object of "Second" in the Main.java and call the fields and methods from Second. And then I compiled both of the file and it output the result of the fields and methods from Second. Then I put one more method in the Second.java file and call that method in the Main.java. At that time, I only have to recompile the Main.java file and that method was called. I don't have to recompile the Second.java file. How's that work? Doesn't the Second.java file has to be recompiled after some modification?

( I used the notepad for better understanding of java compiling process)

Comment: Could you show us your code? At least the modifications?

Comment: Second.java would need to be recompiled for you to use the new method in Main.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`javac` automatically recompiles dependencies when it finds a corresponding `.java` file.

You will notice that if you delete both `.class` files and build only `Main.java` with `javac Main.java`, then `Second.class` will still be generated.

If you then delete or move `Second.java` but leave `Second.class` in place, and modify `Main.java` to call a new method, then `javac` will find the old class, be unable to recompile it, and give you the error about missing methods that you expected.

Comment: Thanks all. I understand how's that work  with all of your helps. I'm really appreciate all of you.